# c++ template class. I am having an errors that I do not understand. about 30 of them

Tags: c++, matrix

what i want to achieve is to maintain a template matrix class but there some errors(about 30 errors which is alot) that i dont really understand. please help!!
some of  the errors:
'identifier' : undeclared identifier, it show up for col, row and T.
unrecognizable template declaration/definition.
'operator <<': looks like a function definition, but there is no parameter list.
 syntax error: ''

```
template <int row, int col, typename T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Matrix<row, col,T>& other) 

{ 

    return other.print(out); 
}

template <int row, int col, typename T>

Matrix<row, col, T>& operator+(T number, const Matrix<row, col, T>& other) 
{

    Matrix<other.getRow(), other.getCol(), T> numMat(number);

    return (numMat + other);
}

template <int row, int col, typename T = int>

class Matrix {

public:

    Matrix(T number);

    Matrix();

    Matrix(const Matrix<row, col, T>& other);

    int getRow();

    int getCol();

    Matrix& operator+(const Matrix<row, col, T>& other);

    Matrix& operator-(const Matrix<row, col, T>& other);

    Matrix& operator+(T number);

    Matrix& operator-(T number);

    Matrix& operator++();

    Matrix& operator--();

    Matrix& operator++(int);

    Matrix& operator--(int);

    Matrix& operator*(T number);

    T& operator()(int a, int b);

    ostream& print(ostream& out) const;

    T trace();

    ~Matrix();

private:

    int _row, _col;

    T** matrix;

};




template <int row, int col, typename T>

Matrix<row, col, T>:: Matrix(T number) {

    _row = row;

    _col = col;

    matrix = new T*[_row];

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {

        matrix[i] = T[_col];

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < _row; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < _col; j++) {

            matrix[i][j] = number;


        }

    }

}


template <int row, int col, typename T = int >

Matrix<row, col, T>::Matrix() {

    _row = row;

    _col = col;

    matrix = new T*[_row];

    for (int i = 0; i < _row; i++) {

        matrix[i] = T[_col];

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < _row; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < _col; j++) {

            matrix[i][j] = 1;

        }

    }

}


template <int row, int col, typename T>

Matrix<row, col, T>::Matrix(const Matrix<row, col, T>& other) {

    _row = other._row;

    _col = other._col;

    matrix = new T*[_row];

    for (int i = 0; i < _row; i++) {

        matrix[i] = new T[_col];

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < _row; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < _col; j++) {

            matrix[i][j] = other.matrix[i][j];

        }

    }

}



template <int row, int col, typename T>

int Matrix<row, col, T>::getRow() {

    return _row;

}

template <int row, int col, typename T>

int Matrix<row, col, T>::getCol() {

    return _col;

}

template <int row, int col, typename T>

Matrix<row, col, T>& Matrix<row, col, T>::operator+(const Matrix<row, col, T>& 
other) {

    Matrix<getRow(), getCol(), T> mat1;

    for (int i = 0; i < _row; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < _row; j++) {

            mat1.matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j] + other.matrix[i][j];

        }

    }

    return mat1;

}


template <int row, int col, typename T>

Matrix<row, col, T><row, col, T>::operator-(const Matrix<row, col, T>& other) {

    Matrix<getRow(), getCol(), T> mat1;

    for (int i = 0; i < _row; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < _row; j++) {

            mat1.matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j] - other.matrix[i][j];

        }

    }

    return mat1;

}


template <int row, int col, typename T>

Matrix<row, col, T>& Matrix<row, col, T>::operator+(T number) {

    Matrix<getRow(), getCol(), T> mat1;

    for (int i = 0; i < _row; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < _col; j++) {

            mat1.matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j] + number;

        }

    }

    return mat1;
}


template <int row, int col, typename T>

Matrix<row, col, T>& Matrix<row, col, T>::operator-(T number) {

    Matrix<getRow(), getCol(), T> mat1;

    for (int i = 0; i < _row; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < _col; j++) {

            mat1.matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j] - number;

        }

    }

    return mat1;

}


template <int row, int col, typename T>

Matrix<row, col, T>& Matrix<row, col, T>::operator++() {

    for (int i = 0; i < _row; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < _col; j++) {

            ++matrix[i][j];

        }

    }

    return *this;

}


template <int row, int col, typename T>

Matrix<row, col, T>& Matrix<row, col, T>::operator--() {

    for (int i = 0; i < _row; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < _col; j++) {

            --matrix[i][j];

        }

    }

    return *this;

}


template <int row, int col, typename T>

Matrix<row, col, T>& Matrix<row, col, T>::operator++(int) {

    Matrix<row, col, T> tmp(Matrix);

    ++(*this);

    return tmp;

}


template <int row, int col, typename T>

Matrix<row, col, T>& Matrix<row, col, T>::operator--(int) {

    Matrix<row, col, T> tmp(Matrix);

    --(*this);

    return tmp;

}


template <int row, int col, typename T>

Matrix<row, col, T>& Matrix<row, col, T>::operator*(T number) {

    Matrix<getRow(), getCol(), T> mat;

    for (int i = 0; i < _row; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < _col; j++) {

            mat.matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j] * number;

        }

    }

    return mat;

}


template <int row, int col, typename T>

T& Matrix<row, col, T>::operator()(int a, int b) {

    if (a < _row && b < _col) {

        return matrix[a][b];

}

    return NULL;

}


template <int row, int col, typename T>

const ostream& Matrix<row, col, T>::print(ostream& out) const {

    for (int i = 0; i < _row; i++) {

        out << matrix[i] << std::endl;

    }

    return out;

}


template <int row, int col, typename T>

T Matrix<row, col, T>::trace() {

    T tr;

    for (int i = 0; i < _row; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < _col; j++) {

            tr += matrix[i][j];

        }

    }

    return tr;

}


template <int row, int col, typename T>

Matrix<row, col, T>::~Matrix() {

    for (int i = 0; i < _row; i++) {

        delete[]matrix[i];

    }

    delete[]matrix;
}
```

Comment: Shall we guess the errors?

Comment: the errors dont show up when the header is alone it act up when the source file is added which i cant change this one of them that i think may be the main problem

Comment: unrecognizable template declaration/definition

Comment: Try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would suffice if you reduce your matrix class to some bare minimum of methods so that an error occurs. Like this, errors can occur anywhere and there might be several of those. That said, if rows and cols are template parameters, why don't you make the inner container an actual array? That is, if you don't simply opt for changing it into a 2d-std::vector or std::array. Although I assume that you want to do some micro-optimization and therefore use a raw array?

Answer (score 2):

First, post the full text of all the errors.

Second, you have two functions using `Matrix` before it is declared, either put

```
template <int row, int col, typename T = int>
class Matrix;
```

at the top of the file or move `ostream& operator<<` and `Matrix<row, col, T>& operator+` to after the definition of `Matrix`.

Third, you don't need `_row` and `_col` data members, just use the template parameters. If other places need them, you can put this in `Matrix`

```
constexpr int Rows = row;
constexpr int Cols = col;
```

and use it like

```
for (int i = 0; i < my_matrix.Rows; ++i)
```

Fourth, rather than using C arrays, consider instead using [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), as it defines many useful methods, primarily allowing you to use default copy & move constructors and destructors.